# How to remove n number of elements from a list by index in Python?

Tags: python, list

Let us assume,

```
g = ['1', '', '2', '', '3', '', '4', '']
```

I want to delete all `''` from g, where i have to get

```
g = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the '' are always and only at even numbered indices, then here's a solution that actually deletes the items:

```
>>> g = ['1', '', '2', '', '3', '', '4', '']
>>> g[::2]
['1', '2', '3', '4']
>>> g[1::2]
['', '', '', '']
>>> del g[1::2]  #  <-- magic happens here.
>>> g
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

The magic, of course is a **[slice assignment.](http://docs.python.org/release/2.3.5/whatsnew/section-slices.html)**

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> g = ['1', '', '2', '', '3', '', '4', '']
>>> filter(None, g)
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

---

```
Help on built-in function filter in module `__builtin__`:

filter(...)
filter(function or None, sequence) -> list, tuple, or string

   Return those items of sequence for which function(item) is true.  If
   function is None, return the items that are true.  If sequence is a tuple
   or string, return the same type, else return a list.
```

You can also use a list comprehension if you prefer

```
>>> [x for x in g if x!=""]
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

Comment: This is the most Pythonic solution.

Comment: As a side note, `filter` with `None` removes any value that is *falsy*. For example `filter(None, [False, 0, 1, 2, 3])` returns `[1, 2, 3]`

Comment: Disagree about 'most Pythonic'.  Guido van Rossum says of filter: "list comprehensions do the same thing better".  See slide 4 of [python regrets](http://www.python.org/doc/essays/ppt/regrets/PythonRegrets.pdf)

Comment: @wim, `None` isn't a function.

Answer (score 5):

If your list is all strings, use the fact that empty sequences are false in an if statement:

```
>>> g = ['1', '', '2', '', '3', '', '4', '']
>>> [x for x in g if x]
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

Otherwise, use `[x for x in g if x != '']`

Answer (score 4):

```
new_g = [item for item in g if item != '']
```